# mongoose findOneAndUpdate query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose for mongodb queries.

My update query returns `null`.
What am I doing wrong?

The query is as follows:

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate(criteria, updatedDetails, { 'new': true})
```

Example - 
I have a user profile which I need to update and send the updated profile back to frontend.

```
 User.findOneAndUpdate({mobile: "9999999999999"}, { address: "test address" }, {'new': true} )
```

But the result comes **null** instead of the updated profile.

Comment: Please provide at least a sample set of the data you are querying.

Comment: @FlorianSchlag have provided a simple example for the same

Answer (score 0):

**findOneAndUpdate** is now **desprecated** 
 use **update**, here is sample code

```
exports.updateSomething = (req, res) => {
    Model.update({
            _id: req.params.id
        }, {
            $set: {
                bla: req.body.bla
            }
        })
        .then(data => {
            return res.status(200).json({
                success: true,
                message: 'Updated successfully'
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return res.status(200).json({
                success: false,
                message: err.message
            })
        })
}
```

Comment: But it isn't mention anywhere in mongoose official docs.
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate

Comment: Also, i get Deprecated Warning every time i use this method